# How to test app store upgrade scenario on iphone sdk simulator

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm working on iOS app now i need to test what happens when app was upgraded .similar to app store updations
I want to test this scenario on SDK Simulator 
Can any help me how to test this on sdk simulator

Comment: Just increase the Bundle Version in the plist, and run again.

Comment: IT is fine if we run the app again on older version app?

Comment: yes, that's how your app upgrade works.